# algebra - matrices and polynoms

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$T:\mathbb P_2[x]↦\mathbb P_2[x]$ s.t.:

- $T(1)=3+2x+4x^2$,
- $T(x)=2+2x^2$,
- $T(x^2)=4+2x+3x^2$.

Is there base $B$ of $\mathbb P_2[x]$ that $[T]_B$=
\begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 0 & 0\\
    -1 & 1 & 0\\
    5 & 0 & 4\\  \end{bmatrix}

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic polynomial of $T$ appears to be
$$
\lambda^{3} - 6 \lambda^{2} - 15 \lambda - 8,
$$
while that of the target $[T]_{B}$ appears to be
$$
\lambda^{3} - 7 \lambda^{2} +14 \lambda - 8.
$$
As the two do not match, it seems there is no such $B$.

---

> Simpler still, then, just looks at the traces, one is $6$, the other is $7$.